# How to force an image icon and span text which is longer than one line have the 1st line aligned with the image icon?

Tags: html, css, html-table

When a  span text is longer than one line, it's not aligned properly with the image icon. How can I make it happen?

Currently, if the image and span text are present in one line then its aligned properly.

I tried the following:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <TD>
      <INPUT type=text id="item_name" name=item_namelength=25 maxlength=100 value="<%=item_name%>" onchange="verifyItemInfo()">
      <TD><span id="signalSrc">
    <img  align="top" src="../images/warning.png"></span> </TD>
      <TD><span class=dfb9 id="ajaxGetItems" style="color: #ff0000;  
    display: inline-block;">There is a really long text which goes to the 
    next line and then the alignment doesnt work</span> </TD>
  </TR>
</table>
```

Comment: what exacly do you want to achieve?

Comment: Basically, when we type something in the textbox, it does an ajax call to the backend and displays a message to the user along with an  image icon , the message displayed can be in one line or 2 lines depending on the situation. Thus, the image icon should be aligned with the span text's 1st line

Comment: You're better off ditching the table altogether and doing something more like this:
https://codepen.io/misterManSam/pen/ZEEpxYz

Answer (score 0):

If i am guessing correctly of what you need, the 'mis-alignment' may be due to the fact that the content are being `vertical-align: middle`. To fix this, you might try to add `line-height` and `vertical-align: top`as needed.

```css
tr {
  line-height: 20px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <TD>
      <INPUT type=text id="item_name" name=item_namelength=25 maxlength=100 value="<%=item_name%>" onchange="verifyItemInfo()">
      <TD><span id="signalSrc">
    <img  align="top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/20"></span> </TD>
      <TD><span class=dfb9 id="ajaxGetItems" style="color: #ff0000;  
    display: inline-block;">There is a really long text which goes to the 
    next line and then the alignment doesnt work. Long Long Long Long Long Long Long</span> </TD>
  </TR>
</table>
```